# Save user input data into a List

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

is there a possible way to save user input data into a list in Flutter ?
As an example: the user has the option of inserting as many text fields as he wants via a button. The Textfield has a default value.
If the user wants, he can change the value.
The entered value should be saved to a List or a Map.
Something like that:

```
|TextfieldName |User Input
|--------------|----------
|Textfield1.   |45
|Textfield2    |40
|Textfield3    |42
```

and so on

For this it would probably be necessary that each textfield/textformfield has a unique ID.

PS: I just want to save the data temporarily and upload it into a database later.

I have added a picture to show the Textfields in my app.

[Textfields in my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxTjs.png)

The map should then also be created in this order, so that if the value 25 changes to 26 at 3, this should also changed in the map.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: have a look at [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). You could store the input with it and load it if you start your app

Comment: Okay thanks, I just want to save the data temporarily and upload it into a database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a list of Strings (`List<String> myList`) and add the results of user-input in the List by `myList.add(userInput)`. Later you can loop to the List and store in the database.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. In this case I have the problem that as soon as a value is changed that was already inserted at the beginning, this value is simply added to the list and I can no longer track which value belongs to which text field.